# Renaming files takes too much memory

Tags: android

I am trying to rename all files with particular extensions. This works fine, however, the process seems slow and sometimes freezes the device for some time. how do i make it take less memory?

```
setContentView(R.layout.transparent_ui);
    // getting SDcard root path
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    walkdir(dir);
    finish();
}

public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = { "the_video_first",
        "webm", "mkv", "flv", "vob", "ogg", "drc", "gif", "gifv", "mng",
        "avi", "mov", "wmv", "yuv", "rm", "rmvb", "asf", "mp4", "mpg",
        "mpeg", "mpg", "mpeg", "m4v", "svi", "3gp", "3g2", "mxf",
        "now_the_audio", "wav", "mp3", "wma", "ogg", "m4a",
        "now_the_images", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp" };

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext, ".xghost" + ext);
                }

                listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this library? compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'. it has some good file operations.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this link below it has different implementations

http://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-rename-or-move-a-file

Comment: your answer is totally irrelevant. I hope this was a joke.

Comment: Commons IO, Guava has file operations. They are alternative to java defaults. Replace your "renameTo" method with suitable methods from those libraries. Then check the performance.

Comment: please post an asynstack answer

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ?, can you elaborate your logic. why this internal FOR loop running these many times. how it should be your final path ?

```
for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
  fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext, ".xghost" + ext);
}
```

Comment: As the question says. "I am trying to rename all files with particular extensions." and this works fine. Please read the question before posting anything. Thanks.

Comment: I have understood your question of "replacing file name", i also trying to understanding part of the code which is placed in else part, what is doing -  for any file path, for loop is running at length of TARGET_EXTENSIONS  array size. 
but if you observe for loop code, what it make sense is, file path always ending up with extension .bmp to .xghostbmp

is that your performing ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    // use string builder avoid concatenation inside a loop
                    String oldExt = new StringBuilder().append(".").append(ext).toString();
                    if (fPath.contains(oldExt)) {
                        String newExt  = new StringBuilder().append(".xghost").append(ext).toString();
                        fPath = fPath.replace(oldExt, newExt);
                        listFile[i].renameTo( new File(fPath));
                        break; // no need to continue once we have replaced the extension.
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```